# Is it possible to limit the multitouch to only two fingers?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I get the following error when three or more fingers are pressed at the same time on my app.

```
'JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
        at boolean
```

The following code controlls the multi touch:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
        int pointerID = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        int[] touchX = new int[event.getPointerCount()];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < event.getPointerCount() ; i++){
            touchX[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
        }

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (touchX[0] < screenX / 2) {
                    astronaut.isGoingUp = true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                astronaut.isGoingUp = false;
                if (touchX[0] > screenX / 2) {
                    astronaut.toShot++;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                if(touchX[pointerID] < screenX / 2) {
                    astronaut.isGoingUp = true;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                if(touchX[pointerID] > screenX / 2){
                    astronaut.toShot++;
                }
            default:
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Im guessing it has something to do with that the the `event.getPointerCount()` or the for loop.
Im wondering what im doing wrong when it crashes for more than two fingers, other than that it works completly as inteded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the action with `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` mask for multi-touches, and then return if the number of fingers is greater than 2.

[`getPointerCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getPointerCount()) returns the number of touched fitters at a time.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // More than one down touches
    if ((action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) { 
        int count = event.getPointerCount(); // Number of touched 'fingers' 
        if (count > 2) // return if greater than 2 fingers
            return true;
    }
    
    // Your code here is for one or two fingers
    
}
```